# Notepad++ Input and Ouput Custom Format

Tags: notepad++, plugins

Is it possible to create a plugin for Notepad++ to read a custom format (an encrypted text file) edit it through notepad++ and save it back to the custom format.

I'm thinking that if notepad++ detects the specific file extension it will process the data through the plugin before displaying the contents.

I want to simplify the process of `decode->open->edit->save->encode` to just `open->edit->save`.

**Question**:

- Is it possible with notepad++, if not, is there another editor that has this functionality? (I also use Atom, Sublime)
- Where can I find the related documentation?

Comment: To read encrypted file it needs some crypto key. What's about it?

Comment: @Biswa, And I have it. The question doesn't really have anything to do with encryption.

Answer (score 1):

It's a big question you're asking.

In short...

### Notepad++

I don't know how much you can do in Np++ plugins.  Documentation can be found at https://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html, for example [this](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Development) seems to be a good starting place.

### **Atom**

Certainly, you can do what you want by writing your own Atom Package:

- Start with the Atom Documentation, such as [getting started/flight manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/),
- through the [top-level documentation](https://atom.io/docs), you'll find all the API references you might need,

Examples,

- How to open your file however you like (see [addOpener](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.18.0/Workspace#instance-addOpener)), and
- then manipulating the text (see [TextBuffer](https://atom.io/docs/api/v1.18.0/TextBuffer)).

Hope this helps as a starting point.